# How do I select Just one row for each row in a Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

So I have two Tables: `Customers` and `Calls`.

There is a `one to many` relationship between these tables. *i.e. One Customer can have Many Calls*

I am trying to create a left join so that I have an output where the `Customers` are listed **only once** with the most recent `CallDate`from the `Calls` table.

**Using this diagram:**

[image]

I have constructed the following `SQL` statement:

```
Select Customers.*, Calls.CallDate 
From Customers 
Left Join Calls 
on Customers.Id=Calls.CustomerId
```

But this gives me a separate `Customer` row for each `Call`

How do I get **just one** row for each `Customer` based on the most recent `CallDate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is to use [`Outer Apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
Select c.*, ca.*
From Customers c outer apply
     (select top 1 ca.*
      from Calls ca
      where c.id = ca.CustomerId
      order by CallDate desc
     ) ca;
```

However, if you just want the most recent call date, then aggregation is the typical approach.  One method:

```
select c.*, max_callDate
from customers c left join
     (select CustomerId, max(CallDate) as max_callDate
      from calls
      group by CustomerId
     ) ca
     on c.id = ca.CustomerId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)  window function:

```
Select Customers.*, c.CallDate 
From Customers 
Left Join (
   SELECT CustomerId, CallDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId 
                             ORDER BY CallDate DESC) AS rn         
   FROM Calls 
) AS c on Customers.Id = c.CustomerId AND c.rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION BY` clause enumerates records within `CustomerId` partitions. Number 1 is assigned to the record having the maximum `CallDate` value, due to `ORDER BY CallDate DESC` clause.

Comment: Great answer which does actually work. The only reason why I personally didn't use this query was readability. I wonder how the efficiency of this query stacks up against the more popular `Outer Apply` and `Group By` methods

Comment: @user1 You can tell us by testing both on your actual data!

Comment: So with my result set of around 25,000 rows The `Group By` query took 17 seconds to run. `Row Number` 13 Seconds and `Outer Apply` 15 seconds. Surising results

Answer (score 1):

You can use **outer apply**

```
Select Customers.*, Calls.CallDate 
From Customers 
outer apply (select top 1 * from  Calls c where Customers.Id=c.CustomerId order by c.CallDate desc ) as Calls
```

Answer (score 1):

As you'll ever only want **one** result, you can code with **`CROSS APPLY`**:

```
Select Customers.*, c.CallDate 
  From Customers 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *  Calls 
           WHERE Customers.Id=Calls.CustomerId ORDER BY CallDate DESC) c
```

If you expect some customers to not have calls (`OUTER JOIN`) you can do `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Further reading [http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/421637/Difference-between-CROSS-APPLY-and-OUTER-APPLY-of](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/421637/Difference-between-CROSS-APPLY-and-OUTER-APPLY-of) about `Apply's` says that a `Cross Apply` is equivilent to an `Inner Join` While an `Outer Apply` is equivilent to a `Left Outer Join`. From the question this would suggest I would be more likely to use the `Outer Apply` but it is probably worth mentioning both here